# how can I send parameter to awk using shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have this file

#### myfile

```
a b c d e 1  
b c s d e 1  
a b d e f 2  
d f g h j 2
```

```
awk 'if $6==$variable {print @0}' myfile
```

How can I use this code in shell script that get `$variable` as parameter by user in command prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk`'s `-v` flag. And since `awk` prints by default, you can try for example:

```
variable=1
awk -v var=$variable '$6 == var' file.txt
```

Results:

```
a b c d e 1
b c s d e 1
```

*EDIT:*

The command is essentially the same, wrapped up in shell. You can use it in a shell script with multiple arguments like this `script.sh 2 j`

Contents of `script.sh`:

```
command=$(awk -v var_one=$1 -v var_two=$2 '$6 == var_one && $5 == var_two' file.txt)
echo -e "$command"
```

Results:

```
d f g h j 2
```

Comment: yes .. but i want use this code in .sh file and run this file with arguments. for example prg.sh 1

Comment: Note that you don't even need `-v`, but can do: `awk '$6 == var' var=$variable input-file`

Answer (score 0):

This is question 24 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ (http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24) but the most commonly used alternatives with the most common reasons to pick between the 2 are:

```
-v var=value '<script>' file1 file2
if you want the variable to be populated in the BEGIN section
```

or:

```
'<script>' file1 var=value file2
if you do not want the variable to be populated in the BEGIN section and/or need to change the variables value between files
```